# ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedWallet is not a function

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, ethers.js

I have the following code to create my own wallet:

```
var ethers = require('ethers')

    let data = {"address":....}
    var password = "***";
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    ethers.Wallet.provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3.currentProvider);
    ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedWallet(json, password).then(function (wallet) {
        console.log("Wallet address: " + wallet.address);
    });
```

But it does not work because: `TypeError: ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedWallet is not a function`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe this used to work under ethers^3.0.15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's a problem with documentation

The correct function is [Wallet.fromEncryptedJson](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-wallet.html#fromencryptedjson)

From their [unit test](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/061b0eae1d4c570aedd9bee1971afa43fcdae1a6/tests/test-wallet.js#L18)

```
return Wallet.fromEncryptedJson(test.json, test.password).then(...
```

Comment: it is the same that Im doing, previously Wallet is defined as "ethers.Wallet"

Comment: @sapiensapiens There's a small difference: `fromEncryptedWallet` ---> `fromEncryptedJson`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
 const encryptedJson = fs.readFileSync('./.encryptedKey.json', 'utf8');
  let wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJsonSync(
    encryptedJson,
    process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD
  );
  wallet = wallet.connect(provider);
```

Don't bother adding the new" keyword before "ethers.Wallet(...) that will create an error in ethers v6.11.0"